# No such entity issue while placing order in front end?

Tags: magento2

How to fix the  no such entity issue error in front end while placing the order. I have tried to setup update queries for store table but it is not worked. Please help me to fix this

This is the function showing error

```
public function getActive($cartId, array $sharedStoreIds = [])
    {
        $quote = $this->get($cartId, $sharedStoreIds);
        if (!$quote->getIsActive()) {           
            throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', $cartId);

        }
        return $quote;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using any third party module for checkout? like shipping etc?

Comment: using print&mail, electronic delivery, print &mail 3 days

Comment: Can you disable the 3rd party extension and test?

Comment: i am having multiple vendor setup

Comment: How to hide this error for throw

Comment: You need to figure out if its coming from 3rd party extension or not. As I faced similar issue and found it on 3rd party extension.